# Despues de un UPDATE , ejecuto un select pero los datos no se actualizan

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

estoy trabajando JPA , ejecuto el siguiente update:

```
  public int EditarUsuario(UserSys us) {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE `user_sys` "
                + "SET "
                + "`USER_NOM` = ?, "
                + "`USER_ESTADO` = ?, "
                + "`USER_ROL` = ? "
                + "WHERE `USER_ID` = ?; ");
        q.setParameter(1, us.getUserNom());
        q.setParameter(2, us.getUserEstado());
        q.setParameter(3, us.getUserRol());
        q.setParameter(4, us.getUserId());
        int v = q.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return v;
    } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException ex) {
        return 0;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Funciona perfecto , ya que al ejecutar la consulta sobre mysql directamente veo la actualización , sin embargo al hacer el `select * from` de esa tabla no veo en los cambios en jpa:

```
 public List<UserSys> Buscartodos() {
   EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
   em.clear();

    try {
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_sys ;", UserSys.class);
       List<UserSys> lista=q.getResultList();

        return lista;

    } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException ex) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

He hecho inserts y funcionan y actualizan los datos , en este caso que  puede estar pasando?

Comment: Lo que comentas es extraño. Intenta ejecutar `EntityManager#flush` luego `EntityManager#clear` y por último ejecutar tu query.

Comment: Perfecto fue agregarle el   em.flush();
        em.clear();

Comment: Lo bueno es que funcionó, lo malo es que me parece que tienes un problema más grave, porque en escenarios normales no debes acudir a dichos métodos.

Comment: Porque usar native queries para tareas tan genéricas? y más aún usando JPA. Tu método `getEntityManager()` hace un simple llamado a `createEntityManager()` del `EntityManagerFactory`? En realidad no tienes que invocar `flush` o `clear` para esto. Te comparto esto, podría ayudarte https://github.com/ropherpanama/Curso_JPA/blob/master/src/com/jpa/test/JPATest.java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luego de cerrar la transacción y cerrar el `EntityManager`, las operaciones son correctamente perpetuadas en tu base de datos y futuras consultas, por ser nuevas transacciones, podrán leer los cambios realizados por transacciones anteriores.

El tuyo es un caso muy peculiar, puesto que explicas que a pesar de cerrar la transacción y el `EntityManager`, es como si no se hubiesen reflejado los cambios hechos en la base de datos, asumiendo que estas operaciones las ejecutas de manera secuencial y que se han cerrado todas las sesiones antes de ejecutar tu sentencia `SELECT`.

En todo caso, puedes acudir a los métodos `EntityManager#flush` y `EntityManager#clear`, en ese orden, para que todas las operaciones se ejecuten y que puedas ver los cambios reflejados. El código de tu consulta quedaría como sigue:

```
public List<UserSys> Buscartodos() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.flush();
    em.clear();
    try {
    /*
        resto de tu código
        incluye cerrar este bloque try y aplicar finally
        para cerrar los recursos
    */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se solucionó agregando

```
em.flush();
em.clear();`
```

Antes de ejecutar el `select * from`

Comment: Aunque no estas obligado, podrias marcar la respuesta de Luiggi como **respuesta aceptada** ya que parece que fue lo que te ayudo a resolver tu problema. Ademas otros usuarios encuentran la respuesta mas facil

Comment: Daniel, agrega esta actualización en tu respuesta, porque seguramente borraran esta respuesta, saludos!.